# URL routing on render is not working for my React and Express JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router-dom, render.com

I have created a React, Express JS application. On my localhost the routing works correctly.

But when I uploaded the application to Render, the routing doesn't work.

For example in the image:

[image]

This is how looks my App.js

```jsx
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<AllSectionsPage />} />
          <Route path="/admin/login" element={<LoginPage />} />

          {/*Protected Routes*/}
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route
              path="/admin/reservation/overview"
              element={<ReservationsOverView />}
            />
            <Route path="/admin/logout" element={<Logout />} />
            <Route path="/admin/pricing" element={<Pricing />} />
            <Route
              path="/admin/calendar-settings"
              element={<CalendarSettings />}
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my app.js (Express)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const path = require('path')

//new scheme routes
const reservationRoutes = require("./routes/Reservation/reservation")
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/Admin/admin")

const port = 8000
//middleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public"))) // Built React app

//new scheme routes
app.use("/api/reservations",reservationRoutes)
app.use("/api/admin",adminRoutes)


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Looks like an issue with how Express serves your static content. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant server-side code

Comment: Maybe, but I thought the problem was on the react side, not the Express Js side.

Comment: That error you're seeing comes from Express

Comment: I provided my app.js (Express) code

Comment: Ok, so compare that to the answer in the linked post. You need a `/*` route handler and it should be registered last